# (TSQL) INSERT doubling time of the query

Tags: performance, t-sql, optimization, insert

I have a quite complex multi-join TSQL SELECT query that runs for about 8 seconds and returns about 300K records. Which is currently acceptable. But I need to reuse results of that query several times later, so I am inserting results of the query into a temp table. Table is created in advance with columns that match output of SELECT query. But as soon as I do INSERT INTO ... SELECT - execution time more than doubles to over 20 seconds! Execution plans shows that 46% of the query cost goes to "Table Insert" and 38% to Table Spool (Eager Spool).

Any idea why this is happening and how to speed it up?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using the `tempdb` when doing the insert into the temp table - that also takes resources...

Comment: I understand that, but I need to speed this up.
Also, I just tried SELECT INTO instead of INSERT INTO - and that increased time only 2 seconds - which is a lot faster... Strange.

Comment: Have you declared an index on the temp table? Are you inserting the records in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Why" of it hard to say, we'd need a lot more information. (though my SWAG would be that it has to do with logging...)

However, the solution, 9 times out of 10 is to use SELECT INTO to make your temp table.

Comment: Yup it is defined faster. Using this together with no locks gave quite a boost

Comment: (No Locks) has no effect on statements like SELECT INTO and INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at standard tuning itmes.  Is disk performing?  Are there sufficient resources (IOs, RAM, CPU, etc)?  Is there a bottleneck in the RDBMS?  Does sound like the issue but what is happening with locking?  Does other code give similar results?  Is other code performant?

Answer (score 1):

A few things I can suggest based on the information you have provided. If you don't care about dirty reads, you could always change the transaction isolation level (if you're using MS T-SQL)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
select ...
```

This may speed things up on your initial query as locks will not need to be done on the data you are querying from. If you're not using SQL server, do a google search for how to do the same thing with the technology you are using.

For the insert portion, you said you are inserting into a temp table. Does your database support adding primary keys or indexes on your temp table? If it does, have a dummy column in there that is an indexed column. Also, have you tried to use a regular database table with this? Depending on your set up, it is possible that using that will speed up your insert times.